# Xaml MergedDictionaries in code behind Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

I want to change some colors during runtime in my app (UAP Windows10).
Im' doing it like this

```
while (App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count() > 2)
{
  App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count() - 1);
}

if (index < 0 || index > 2) { index = 0; }
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri(App.uri_colors[(int)index], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```

It's working for the first time when the Application starts, but the colors don't change while running. The Current values changed though.

Do I need to refresh something? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you reference the resources using DynamicResource?

Comment: My resources are stored in 3 different files (RED.xaml, GREEN.xaml, BLUE.xaml). I created a static List<string> whith the 3 different string uri. Or wasn't that you question?

Comment: No, my question is, how do you use the resources. Like Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}"

Comment: Sorry. Background="{StaticResource app_color}"

Comment: Change it to DynamicResource

Comment: I can't choose DynamicResource?! I could choose CustomResource, but I need extra stuff isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes I didn't realise you're doing a Windows Store app. DynamicResource is not available there. I'm not sure what the official alternative is. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286430/dynamicresource-in-windows-store-app-apps) question for some tips.

Comment: Thanks anyway... I'll try out a bit...